# Chart.js axes label font size

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chart.js how can I set the set the font size for just the x axis labels without touching global config?

I've already tried setting the 'scaleFontSize' option my options object.
I've also tried setting:

```
{
  ...
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      scaleFontSize: 40
      ...
    }]
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Comment: The title should be changed, since the question and the answers focus on the axis tick labels and not the actual axis label, which is confusing if you are looking to change the axis label font size.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `fontSize` attribute is actually in `scales.xAxes.ticks` and not in `scales.xAxes` as you thought.

So you just have to edit the attribute like this :

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 40
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

---

You can see a [fully working example in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zxguLps/) and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how to set fontSize for radar chart where no `x` and `y` axes ?

Comment: You referenced the xAxes ticks in your explanation, but set the yAxes ticks to 40 in the jsFiddle.

Comment: How could I set the title's and lable's font size ?

Comment: This is working in fiddle but not in my code.

Answer (score 73):

Configuration options and properties for chartjs 3.0 has changed. Currently I'm using Chartjs [3.1.1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.1.1/). [Fonts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) are used as objects now. In order to change font size of x axis ticks you have to use following configuration.

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        x: {
            ticks: {
                font: {
                    size: 12,
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvr61u74/4/) sample.

Comment: Finally! I've searched everywhere and most of the other answers are outdated!

Comment: Here is the doc link: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/fonts.html

Comment: It still works also for chart.js v4.3.0 :)

Answer (score 11):

```
options: {
                  locale: 'fa-IR',
                  responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
                  maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
                        plugins: {
                          legend: {
                              position: 'top',
                              labels: {
                                  font: {
                                    size: 9,
                                    family:'vazir'
                                  }
                             }
                          },
                          title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: chart_info.chartTitle,
                            font: {
                                size: 16,
                                family:'vazir'
                            }
                          },
                          tooltip: {
                              bodyFont: {
                                size: 13,
                                family:'vazir'
                              }
                         }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            ticks: {
                                font: {
                                    size: 10,
                                    family:'vazir'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                font: {
                                    size: 10,
                                    family:'vazir'
                                }
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Does not work for Radial type

Answer (score 8):

Try this is working

```js
     options: {
        scales: {
           xAxes: [{
                   ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10
                   }
                  }]
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to see if this will work

```
{
  ...
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      fontSize: 40
      ...
    }]
   }
}
```

It doesn't look like `scaleFontSize` is a valid property.

Comment: Surprisingly is works for the `scaleLabel` which is poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 8;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: As of April 2023, this does not work. However the following text works for the global configuration: `Chart.defaults.font.size = 16;` Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

```
myChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 40 ;

myChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm using ^2.9.4 chart.js. I've tried other solutions posted here and did some tweak.

```
    options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          minor: {
             fontSize: 16
          }
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          minor: {
             fontSize: 16
          }
        }
      }]
     }
   }
```