# How to increase size and family in a radar's Chartjs label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I would like to increase the size and change color of the font in a chart label, but it's not the legend label. It is the name in the side of each data of the radar chart.

[image]

I tried doing this:

```
    options={{
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontStyle: "bold"
                    }
                },
```

But it only changes the name of the 'Undefined' label.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hope helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305167/1374554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options: {
  scale: {
    pointLabels: {
      fontSize: 16
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what to do on mobile coz this makes the chart skewed , do we need to change font size or what ??

Answer (score 2):

To someone come from Chart.js v 3.7.1 or + the configuration is a bit changed the below code won't work anymore.

```js
options: {
  scale: {
    pointLabels: {
      fontSize: 16
    }
  }
}
```

Use this one

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    r: {
      pointLabels: {
        font: {
          size: 16
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a configured radar grid.

- Label size is set via: `options.scale.pointLabels.fontSize`
- Label color is set via: `options.scale.pointLabels.fontColor`
- Legend font color is set via: `options.legend.labels.fontColor`

The docs are pretty good, you should check them out:

- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html
- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html

```js
var skillCanvas = document.getElementById('skillChart');
var skillData = {
  labels: ["Teamwork", "Organization", "Adaptability", "Curiousity", "Self-taught"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Student A",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 192, 145, 0.2)',
    data: [90, 80, 92, 88, 75]
  }]
};
var skillChart = new Chart(skillCanvas, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: skillData,
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#11c091'
      }
    },
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        color: '#AAA'
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: false,
        max: 100,
        min: 20,
        stepSize: 10,
        fontColor: '#fff',
        backdropColor: '#444'
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontColor: '#11c091'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<canvas id="skillChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```